# Common periods between all data sets where there are no NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

For 3 data frames of values measured each 10 seconds through 6 months, I want to compare these data frames but the problem is that they contain many gaps of missing values at different times through those 6 months.
Now, I am trying to find a method to compare these 3 data frames in order to **find common periods between the 3 data frames where there are no missing values.**So I want to know for which dates and times exactly there are data in all data frames in order to extract these data and to continue my analysis.

As an example, here is an input data

```
#df1
           date     V1   
2010-02-01 00:00:00 15278
2010-02-01 00:00:10 15257
2010-02-01 00:00:20 15273
2010-02-01 00:00:30 15386
2010-02-01 00:00:40 15333
2010-02-01 00:00:50 15360
2010-02-01 00:01:00 17357
2010-02-01 00:01:10 na
2010-02-01 00:01:20 na
2010-02-01 00:01:30 na
2010-02-01 00:01:40 na
2010-02-01 00:01:50 14214
2010-02-01 00:02:00 na
2010-02-01 00:02:10 14233
2010-02-01 00:02:20 14183
2010-02-01 00:02:30 14100
2010-02-01 00:02:40 14070
2010-02-01 00:02:50 na
...
```

and for `df2`

```
#df2
           date     V2   
2010-02-01 00:00:00 15
2010-02-01 00:00:10 12
2010-02-01 00:00:20 13
2010-02-01 00:00:30 16
2010-02-01 00:00:40 13
2010-02-01 00:00:50 15
2010-02-01 00:01:00 17
2010-02-01 00:01:10 na
2010-02-01 00:01:20 na
2010-02-01 00:01:30 na
2010-02-01 00:01:40 na
2010-02-01 00:01:50 16
2010-02-01 00:02:00 na
2010-02-01 00:02:10 14
2010-02-01 00:02:20 11
2010-02-01 00:02:30 10
2010-02-01 00:02:40 13
2010-02-01 00:02:50 17
...
```

for `df3`

```
#df3
           date     V3   
2010-02-01 00:00:00 11278
2010-02-01 00:00:10 11257
2010-02-01 00:00:20 11273
2010-02-01 00:00:30 12386
2010-02-01 00:00:40 13333
2010-02-01 00:00:50 na
2010-02-01 00:01:00 11357
2010-02-01 00:01:10 na
2010-02-01 00:01:20 na
2010-02-01 00:01:30 na
2010-02-01 00:01:40 na
2010-02-01 00:01:50 12542
2010-02-01 00:02:00 na
2010-02-01 00:02:10 na
2010-02-01 00:02:20 13183
2010-02-01 00:02:30 14100
2010-02-01 00:02:40 18850
2010-02-01 00:02:50 14770
...
```

and the output result must be

```
2010-02-01 00:00:00 to 2010-02-01 00:00:40
2010-02-01 00:01:00 to 2010-02-01 00:01:00 # as data available at this time in al data frames
2010-02-01 00:01:50 to 2010-02-01 00:01:50 # as data available at this time in al data frames
2010-02-01 00:02:20 to 2010-02-01 00:02:40
```

Comment: I believe you can use `left_join` to combine the three data frames into a single data frame instead of finding the range. This will make your downstream analysis simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following operations. Below are the data in readable format.

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date,      ~V1,    
"2010-02-01 00:00:00", 15278,
"2010-02-01 00:00:10", 15257,
"2010-02-01 00:00:20", 15273,
"2010-02-01 00:00:30", 15386,
"2010-02-01 00:00:40", 15333,
"2010-02-01 00:00:50", 15360,
"2010-02-01 00:01:00", 17357,
"2010-02-01 00:01:10", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:20", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:30", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:40", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:50", 14214,
"2010-02-01 00:02:00", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:02:10", 14233,
"2010-02-01 00:02:20", 14183,
"2010-02-01 00:02:30", 14100,
"2010-02-01 00:02:40", 14070,
"2010-02-01 00:02:50", NA)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date,     ~V2,   
"2010-02-01 00:00:00", 15,
"2010-02-01 00:00:10", 12,
"2010-02-01 00:00:20", 13,
"2010-02-01 00:00:30", 16,
"2010-02-01 00:00:40", 13,
"2010-02-01 00:00:50", 15,
"2010-02-01 00:01:00", 17,
"2010-02-01 00:01:10", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:20", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:30", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:40", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:01:50", 16,
"2010-02-01 00:02:00", NA,
"2010-02-01 00:02:10", 14,
"2010-02-01 00:02:20", 11,
"2010-02-01 00:02:30", 10,
"2010-02-01 00:02:40", 13,
"2010-02-01 00:02:50", 17)

df3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date, ~ V3, 
  "2010-02-01 00:00:00", 11278,
  "2010-02-01 00:00:10", 11257,
  "2010-02-01 00:00:20", 11273,
  "2010-02-01 00:00:30", 12386,
  "2010-02-01 00:00:40", 13333,
  "2010-02-01 00:00:50", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:00", 11357,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:10", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:20", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:30", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:40", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:01:50", 12542,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:00", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:10", NA,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:20", 13183,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:30", 14100,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:40", 18850,
  "2010-02-01 00:02:50", 14770)
```

First, you can make sure that the dates are in the appropriate date format.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date))
df3 <- df3 %>% mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date))
```

Save the original data frames for use later:

```
df1_orig <- df1
df2_orig <- df2
df3_orig <- df3
```

Then, listwise delete all of the data

```
df1 <- na.omit(df1)
df2 <- na.omit(df2)
df3 <- na.omit(df3)
```

Next, you need `inner_join()` because it only keeps the observations that are common to both datasets.

```
df_all <- inner_join(df1, df2)
df_all <- inner_join(df_all, df3)
```

Now, `df_all` only has complete data common to all three datasets.  Then you can take the lag (previous observation) of the date and evaluate whether that is 10 seconds prior to the current observation, in which case the `cont` value will be 0 or if it is more than 10 seconds away in which the `cont` variable will be 1.  By taking the cumulative sum of the `cont` variable, it will identify different groups of sequential observations in the data.

```
df_all <- df_all %>% 
  mutate(lag_date = lag(date), 
         cont = as.numeric(lag_date != (date - lubridate::hms("00:00:10"))), 
         cont = ifelse(is.na(cont), 1, cont), 
         group = cumsum(cont))
```

Finally, you can group by the `group` variable and then find the minimum and maximum of `date` within each group.

```
res <- df_all %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(start = min(date), end = max(date))
res
# 
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   group start               end                
# * <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1     1 2010-02-01 00:00:00 2010-02-01 00:00:40
# 2     2 2010-02-01 00:01:00 2010-02-01 00:01:00
# 3     3 2010-02-01 00:01:50 2010-02-01 00:01:50
# 4     4 2010-02-01 00:02:20 2010-02-01 00:02:40
```

I know you've got a lot of data so hopefully this will be fast enough.  My experience is that the `dplyr` functions seem to scale better than their base R counterparts, so hopefully that will be the case here.

---

### Edit: Filter Original Data

To filter the original data to include only these times, you could do the following:

```
keep_times <- res %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(date = list(seq(from=start, to=end, by=lubridate:::hms("00:00:10")))) %>% 
  unnest(date) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(date)
```

The code above makes a sequence of 10 second intervals from the start to end times in each row.  Then it un-nests the list and then it just keeps the sequence.  You can then left_join this to the original data:

```
d1 <- left_join(keep_times, df1_orig)
d2 <- left_join(keep_times, df2_orig)
d3 <- left_join(keep_times, df3_orig)
```

Here is the result:

```
d1
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#   date                   V1
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2010-02-01 00:00:00 15278
# 2 2010-02-01 00:00:10 15257
# 3 2010-02-01 00:00:20 15273
# 4 2010-02-01 00:00:30 15386
# 5 2010-02-01 00:00:40 15333
# 6 2010-02-01 00:01:00 17357
# 7 2010-02-01 00:01:50 14214
# 8 2010-02-01 00:02:20 14183
# 9 2010-02-01 00:02:30 14100
# 10 2010-02-01 00:02:40 14070

d2
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#   date                   V2
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2010-02-01 00:00:00    15
# 2 2010-02-01 00:00:10    12
# 3 2010-02-01 00:00:20    13
# 4 2010-02-01 00:00:30    16
# 5 2010-02-01 00:00:40    13
# 6 2010-02-01 00:01:00    17
# 7 2010-02-01 00:01:50    16
# 8 2010-02-01 00:02:20    11
# 9 2010-02-01 00:02:30    10
# 10 2010-02-01 00:02:40    13

d3
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#   date                   V3
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2010-02-01 00:00:00 11278
# 2 2010-02-01 00:00:10 11257
# 3 2010-02-01 00:00:20 11273
# 4 2010-02-01 00:00:30 12386
# 5 2010-02-01 00:00:40 13333
# 6 2010-02-01 00:01:00 11357
# 7 2010-02-01 00:01:50 12542
# 8 2010-02-01 00:02:20 13183
# 9 2010-02-01 00:02:30 14100
# 10 2010-02-01 00:02:40 18850
```

Comment: I am very grateful for this great and efficient answer which is, additionally, very fast for my huge data. If I can as an additional related question, could you please clarify how can I sample(or return) the values for the variables in the resulted common periods.

Comment: For example, how can I efficiently return the data of df1, df2 and df3 as

**df1**: `2010-02-01 00:00:00 15278
2010-02-01 00:00:10 15257
2010-02-01 00:00:20 15273
2010-02-01 00:00:30 15386
2010-02-01 00:00:40 15333
2010-02-01 00:01:00 17357
2010-02-01 00:01:50 12542
2010-02-01 00:02:20 13183
2010-02-01 00:02:30 14100
2010-02-01 00:02:40 18850` 
**df2:** `2010-02-01 00:00:00 15
2010-02-01 00:00:10 12
2010-02-01 00:00:20 13
2010-02-01 00:00:30 16
2010-02-01 00:00:40 13
2010-02-01 00:01:00 17
2010-02-01 00:01:50 16
2010-02-01 00:02:20 11
2010-02-01 00:02:30 10` ... and for df3

Comment: @Jean I edited the answer to include how you could get the original data to show you only those rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am so sorry for taking your time for a last question. I applied your solution on the same type of data but with a time lag of 10 minutes instead of 10 seconds. It worked perfectly except the code to make a sequence in the edit part `mutate(date = list(seq(from=start, to=end, by=lubridate:::hms("00:00:10")))) %>%`...I tried `by=lubridate:::hms("00:10:00")` and `by=lubridate:::hm("00:10")` but both didn't work and I got the following error `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : invalid '(to - from)/by'`

Comment: BTW, the data originally with a time lag = 10 seconds but I am modifying it to 10 minutes so your solution works if I keep it as `by=lubridate:::hms("00:00:10")` even I transformed the data to 10 minutes. What is the reason of the above error in your opinion?

Comment: My guess is that the first error happens because the start and end values are not a multiple of 10 minutes apart.  The 10-second intervals work because it will essentially make a long sequence of values separated by 10 seconds.  Even if your values are separated by minutes, this sequence will still identify all of the right values - there will just be lots of extra values that you don't need.